# Best way to union hundreds of datasets in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have 200+ identical databases, each on an separate server, that I am trying to unify into preferably one, but no more than 5 Azure Data Warehouses (AKA Synapse SQL Pool). Because all of the data is identical, I can reuse Azure Data Flows on each database and have all of the data prepared in Azure Data Lake, with a folder of dimension and fact blobs for each database. However, committing 200 * [number of tables] write activities to Azure Data Warehouse is very compute expensive, which translates to very dollar expensive. It would be much better to just have as many write activities as number of tables, but I would have to union the data ahead of this, is there any an easy and resource efficient way to do this in Azure?

Comment: I think you could stage the data using Copy activity to ADLS for each database to a parquet file. After that you could aggregate the data using the copy behaviour "Merge Files" available as Sink in another Copy activity. See: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/merge-multiple-files-in-azure-data-factory

Comment: Wow! That looks like exactly what I need. Thank you so much. I spent hours Googling and never came across this or anything like it. Azure Data Factory really has the absolute worst documentation of any Microsoft product I've ever used.